# Capturing specific application windows with electron app

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, applescript

I am trying to capture an applications window in a similar way to OBS for a personal project. I have tried using electrons desktopCapturer but when I get a list of the running applications I only get the electron app itself and the process that is desktopCapturer.

I am trying to narrow down what I need to search/do to get a stream of an applications window. I am working on macOS right now so that is my starting point but I will be looking into a similar thing for windows and Linux eventually.

Where can I start?

Comment: That has very little to do with Applescript. It would (maybe) be able to make it work on macOS, but you would have to find different solutions for other platforms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.